# Como colocar um link para cada banner no @keyframes

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte código funcionando perfeitamente, porém, preciso que em cada um dos três banners do `@keyframes` tenha um link individual. Há esta possibilidade?

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner {
width: 960px;
height: 350px;
margin: 0 auto;
animation: slide 10s infinite;
animation-direction: alterante;
}

@keyframes slide {

    0%, 30% {
        background-image: url(../imagens/001.jpg);
        }

    35%, 65% {
        background-image: url(../imagens/002.jpg);
        }

    70%, 100% {
        background-image: url(../imagens/003.jpg);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
<a href="seu_link1"><div style="background-image: url('img1');"></a>
<a href="seu_link2"><div style="background-image: url('img2');"></a>
<a href="seu_link3"><div style="background-image: url('img3');"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que não, pôs no caso seu problema e o HTML.

Terá que criar 3 divs da class banner, e no CSS, setalas como display none, em cada tamanho.

Por exemplo:

```
<div class="banner key1"></div>
<div class="banner key2"></div>
<div class="banner key3"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 30%) and (min-width: 0%) {
   .key2, .key3 {
      display:none;
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 65%) and (min-width: 35%) {
   .key1, .key3 {
      display:none;
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 100%) and (min-width: 70%) {
   .key1, .key2 {
      display:none;
   }
}
```